# Some questions regarding Turing's doctoral thesis

Tags: computability, philosophy

Specifically, I am interested in an answer to the following question implicitly raised in Section 4 of his doctoral thesis, *Systems of Logic Based on Ordinals* ("A type of problem which is not number theoretic"):

> What is the degree of unsolvability (Turing degree) of determining for any oracle machine "whether or not it prints an infinity of figures 0 or 1"

Turing asserts (in his thesis) that "this class of problems is not number theoretic", and that"...In view of the definition of 'number theoretic problem' this means to say that it is not possible to construct an oracle machine which when supplied with the description of any other oracle machine will determine whether that machine is circle free (if an oracle machine never writes down more than a finite number of 0's and 1's, it will be called *circular*, otherwise it will be *circle-free*...a oracle machine will be circular if it reaches a configuration from which there is no possible move, or if it goes on moving, and and possibly printing symbols other than 0's and 1's, but cannot print any more 0's or 1's [paraphrase of *Circular and circle-free machines* from _On computable numbers...."])

Is Turing's definition of "Number theoretic theorem and "Number theoretic problem" equivalent to the problem being in the arithmetic hierarchy?  If so, where in the analytic hierarchy does the class of problems under consideration lie?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is clearly in the arithmetic hierarchy (and, in fact, relatively low in that hierarchy), so I looked up Turing's thesis, which is readily available online, to see what he meant.

It turns out that the definition Turing gives for *number-theoretic theorem (or problem)* may have been a bit idiosyncratic even in 1938; he includes a footnote justifying his use of this terminology.  Today people would usually interpret "number-theoretic" to mean "arithmetical", but that's not how Turing used the phrase.

Turing defines, at the beginning of section 3:

> By a *number-theoretic theorem*, we shall mean a theorem of the form
> "$\theta(x)$ vanishes for infinitely many natural numbers $x$", where $\theta(x)$ is a primitive recursive function.

In other words, this is a theorem of the form

$$(\forall x)(\exists y) \; (y\gt x\;\wedge\;\theta(y) = 0)$$

where $\theta$ is primitive recursive.  (The quantifiers here range over natural numbers.)

Turing then continues by saying:

> We shall say that a problem is
> number-theoretic if it has been shown that any solution of the problem
> may be put in the form of a proof of one or more number-theoretic
> theorems. More accurately we may say that a class of problems is
> number-theoretic if the solution of any one of them can be transformed
> (by a uniform process) into the form of proofs of number-theoretic
> theorems.

In modern terms, what Turing calls a *number-theoretic theorem* is a theorem that is $\Pi^0_2,$ as you can see from the format of the $\forall\exists$ formula above.

What Turing calls a *number-theoretic problem* is something that is Turing reducible to a $\Pi^0_2$ set, or, equivalently, that has Turing degree at most $\boldsymbol{0''}.$  [I'm assuming here that when Turing talks about being "transformed (by a uniform process)", he means what we now call Turing reducibility.]

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful. So to translate (so to speak) Turing's statement, "Given any one of these [oracle-] machines we may ask ourselves whether or not it prints an infinity or figures 0 or 1; I assert that this class of problems is not number theoretic", he is essentially stating that the aforementioned class of problems has a Turing degree higher than $\bf 0^{''}$ but still in the arithmetic hierarchy?

Comment: Yes, I think that's right, although I haven't read his whole thesis in detail, unraveling the definitions to match modern terminology.  Skimming it, I think the oracle in his oracle-machines is specifically an oracle for solving instances of the halting problem (he calls it determining if a WFF is *dual*, but I think this is just a rephrasing of the halting problem, which is of degree $\boldsymbol{0'}$).  So, just as determining if a standard (non-oracle) machine prints an infinity of 0s or 1s has degree $\boldsymbol{0''},$ determining this for his o-machines has degree $\boldsymbol{0'''},$

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks.

Comment: Given that Turing's definition of "number-theoretic problem is 'idiosyncratic', I wonder how his definition is related to "elementary arithmetic" (EA) and Harvey Friedman's "Grand Conjecture", "Every theorem published in the Annals of Mathematics whose statement involves only finitary mathematics (i.e., what logicians call an arithmetic statement) can be proved in elementary arithmetic."?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin   Maybe it wasn't fair to call Turing's usage idiosyncratic -- it was really just an early use of the phrase, before modern terminology had crystallized (and before the arithmetical hierarchy had been developed).

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin  In any case, I don't think this sheds any light on Friedman's conjecture.  To me Turing's dissertation reads just like what it is: an early exposition of fundamental ideas which would take a few decades for Turing and many other mathematicians to flesh out and develop.  It's a tribute to Turing that all these ideas are now commonplace for those in the field; they're now well understood, and in a much broader context than was available in Turing's time.  (I think his doctoral thesis is primarily of historical interest at this point.  But I could easily be missing something.)

Comment: Have you any idea what the Turing degree of the decision problem for  Elementary Arithmetic is and how it is related to EA's proof theoretic ordinal (which is $\omega^3$)?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin  I think the set of all consequences of EFA has Turing degree $\boldsymbol{0'},$ like most interesting recursively axiomatizable theories. But I’m not familiar with the proof-theoretic ordinal material on EFA.

Comment: Here is what Turing said about Gentzen's result in his thesis:  "In proving the consistency of a certain system of formal logic Gentzen has made use of  the principle of transfinite induction for ordinals less than $\epsilon_{0}$, and suggested that it is to be expected that transfinite induction carried sufficiently far would suffice to solve all problems of consistency.  Another suggestion to base systems of logic on transfinite induction has been made by Zermelo .  In this section I propose to show how this method of proof may be put into the form of a formal

Comment: (cont.) (non-constructive) logic, and afterwards to obtain from it an ordinal logic."  Given this, and the following statement made by Wolfram Pohlers in his handout, "Introduction to Ordinal Analysis" (see section 1.3), "By Godel's incompleteness theorem it therefore follows that transfinite induction up to $\epsilon_{0}$ cannot be provable from the Peano axioms.  In a later paper he showed that conversely any ordinal less than $\epsilon_{0}$ can be represented by a well-ordering whose well-foundedness is provable in Peano arithmetic.  This was the birth of ordinally informative

Comment: (cont.) proof theory.  Since then we define the proof theoretic ordinal of an axiom system $T$ as the supremum of the order-types of well-orderings which are elementarily definable in the language of $T$ and whose well-foundedness is provable in $T$.", it may very well be that Turing might have contributed to the field of ordinal analysis as well.

Comment: I would say, rather, that Friedman's "Grand Conjecture", if true, would shed light on why Turing would say the $\Pi^{0}_2$ consequences of $EFA$ would be considered "number theoretic" and that determining for any oracle machine "whether or not it prints an infinity of figures 0 or 1" (it is a $\Pi^{0}_3$ problem) would not.